# В чём ошибка PHP-кода?

Tags: php, mysql

День добрый, дамы и господа. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где туплю:

ДАНО:

Имя базы: test_db

Имя таблицы: people

Локальный сервер.

Использую Adminer.

В таблице 4 записи.

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ - тайна белого экрана.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DB</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '123QWErty';
    $db_name ='test_db' ;
    $table = 'people';

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name) or die (mysqli_error($link));

    $query = "SELECT*FROM $table WHERE id>0";

    mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $res = mysqli_connect($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    var_dump($data);


    ?>



</html>
```

Шо ж за Х...ня такая ?

Comment: Доброе утро. Тайну белого экрана можно разгадать заглянув в логи сервера.

Comment: у тебя $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name); по факту засунут в еще один mysqli_connect($link, $query) у тебя отключено отображение ошибок видимо, иначе бы увидел сразу))

Comment: Спасибо. На то я и новичок :) Ищущий да обрящет.

Comment: Исправил (здесь - в самом вопросе), но что-то всё равно не идёт. Я пока не знаю как забраться в потроха того сервера, с которым работаю: тут не так как с openserver, к примеру, не так очевидно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не корректный запрос:

```
 -- $res = mysqli_connect($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Попробуйте так:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $login, $pass);
mysqli_set_charset($connect, 'utf8');

$mysqli_query = mysqli_query( $connect, $query );
mysqli_close( $link );

$arr = [];
while( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqli_query) ){
    array_push( $arr, $result );
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.